# How to establish communication between a computer and a android phone?

Tags: android, sockets, communication

I want to establish communication between an Android phone and a Desktop. The scenario is like this: the phone sends realtime image stream to the Desktop, the Desktop receive those image strams and, process them (to get the moving path of the phone) and then sends result back to the phone.

I have a router so the communication can be done in a local network. How should I do this? I am a newbee for this. My initial understanding is that I should set the desktop as a server. Should I set sockets?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a very complex application. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with it, (and it sounds like you could almost run this entirely on your device without the server part) but here's how I would build these applications in simplified pseudo code:

SERVER

```
Create a socket and listen for clients (this blocks. Use the ServerSocket class)
while(true) {
    wait for image (this blocks)
    process image
    send results back to phone
}
```

Client could be multithreaded, meaning one thread captures images and sends them to the server, and another one listens for results. Here's the single threaded approach:

CLIENT

```
Connect to server (Use Socket class)
while(true) {
    capture image
    send image to server
    wait for results (this blocks)
    process results
}
```

Keep in mind that this will not give you super fast and fluid image stream, maybe 1 picture / second. I'm sure that you can build this application using the camcorder and faster frame rate, but this is a lot easier to start with. Might be enough for your needs, or might not. A video would have to be a stream, which you would process as individual frames on your server.

You can find examples for Socket communication for example from here: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/ and all over StackOverFlow. The API on desktop Java and Android is very similar, if not identical.